# How to determine correct line in errors in Azure AD b2c Policy upload?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Recently I changed the b2C policy and encountered an error

> Run azure-ad-b2c/deploy-trustframework-policy@v1 Error: Action failed:
> Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy
> "B2C_1A_TRUSTFRAMEWORKBASE_LOCALACCOUNT" of tenant
> "x.onmicrosoft.com".Schema validation error found at line 591 col 83
> in policy "B2C_1A_TRUSTFRAMEWORKBASE_LOCALACCOUNT": The element
> 'OutputClaims' in namespace '
> [http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06'](http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06%27) cannot
> contain text. List of possible elements expected: 'OutputClaim' in
> namespace '
> [http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06'.Schema](http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06%27.Schema)
> validation error found at line 564

I tried to find OutputClaims near  line 564 in the file,but the line numbers in the log were  not correct.

The actual silly typo( similar to
[How to resolve Azure B2C UI customization Schema Validation Error pls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69966738/how-to-resolve-azure-b2c-ui-customization-schema-validation-error-pls)
) was  in line   638 inside  the OutputClaims block started from line 632.

Is it a known problem?
Is any way to adjust/ recalculate logged  line numbers to actual line numbers in a file?
I report the problem  to [Microsoft Feedback site](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/ff3fc539-7e10-ee11-a81c-6045bdbc2a74)